# Restore an entire virtualized domain to earlier state?

Tags: vmware-esxi, domain, snapshot, system-restore

We have set up a lab environment in our office to run various cybersecurity simulations. We are using ESXi 6.0 (VMWare) and we have a domain controller with 3 servers.

I know that snapshotting domain controllers can cause problems if they are restored; synchronization issues, etc.

However if we build the network to a stable state, shut everything down and snapshot all the systems there, could we hypothetically revert to those snapshots after an exercise and be OK? If we revert the *entire* network to an earlier state at once, would that work?

I am also concerned about tombstoning active directory, but if we are restoring quickly enough then it shouldn't be an issue... I hear that tombstone tolerances can also be changed with ADSI edit.

Comment: If this is a lab you can do whatever you want. If you only have a single Domain Controller then all of the potential issues regarding snapshotting a DC are irrelevant. Also, have a read here: http://blogs.vmware.com/apps/2013/01/windows-server-2012-vm-generation-id-support-in-vsphere.html

Comment: @joeqwerty Thanks! If there were two domain controllers, but the network was shutdown completely, would there still be issues? Still learning a bit and I know that domain controllers can be finnicky.

Answer (score 1):

If you shut everything down, then take snapshots of everything as they are shutdown, and when you revert back, you shut everything down and revert everything back to the same snapshot, you should be fine.